# Union and right join does not work for missing materials

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one master contract table which has columns such as (VPA_ID, PRODUCT_ID, MATERIAL_NUMBER, QUANTITY). Every product ID has 1:n material numbers and you can see that we have 3 material numbers with amount in the table. The problem is that in this table there are some missing Material number, you can say those material numbers are not mapped in our fact table.
In our Material master this specific product ID has 8 material numbers, out of which 5 are missing in our contract master table. These missing material numbers do not have amounts.

My requirement is that I want to bring missing material numbers in the master contract table. 
I have tried union and right join but it does not work.

Master contract table:

```
select FVPO_VPA_ID as vpa_id, FVPO_price_product_id as product_id, FVPO_material_number as material_number
     , sum(FVPO_Quantity) as quantity                       
from   OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION
where  FVPO_price_product_id = 'PR000349059'
and    FVPO_VPA_ID = '17270'                        
group by FVPO_VPA_ID, FVPO_price_product_id, FVPO_material_number
```

[image]

Material Master:

```
select DSAI_ID, DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR, DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR          
from   OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM
where  DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR = 'PR000349059'
and    dsai_subito_transfer_flag = 'Y'
```

[image]

Expected result:

```
+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+
| FVPO_VPA_ID  |  DSAI_ID |  FVPO_price_product_id |  FVPO_material_number  |  QUANTITY  |
+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+
|        17270 |    40106 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748370           |   5565604  |
|        17270 |    40109 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748364           |   1962898  |
|        17270 |    40108 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748366           |   2589732  |
|              |    11670 |  PR000349059           |  SP000010709           |            |
|              |    40096 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748362           |            |
|              |    40099 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748132           |            |
|              |    40100 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748130           |            |
|              |    40101 |  PR000349059           |  SP000748128           |            |
+--------------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you please share the detailed expected output using the given sample data?

Comment: I am not really clear what amounts you mean or what is missing from where. What does the yellow highlighting indicate? What isn't working?

Comment: What is the relevance of `right join` or union mentioned in question title? neither are used in the question detail.

Comment: Hello experts, I would like to bring the missing material numbers in the fact report. This is what i need as an output:                                                                                         VPA_ID DSAI_ID PRODUCT_ID MATERIAL_NUMBER QUANTITY
17270 40106 PR000349059 SP000748370 5565604
17270 40109 PR000349059 SP000748364 1962898
17270 40108 PR000349059 SP000748366 2589732
       11670 PR000349059 SP000010709 
       40096   PR000349059 SP000748362 
       40099 PR000349059 SP000748132 
      40100    PR000349059 SP000748130 
      40101   PR000349059 SP000748128

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION(
>    FVPO_VPA_ID           VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL 
>   ,DSAI_ID               INTEGER  NOT NULL
>   ,FVPO_price_product_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
>   ,FVPO_material_number  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
>   ,FVPO_Quantity         INTEGER 
> );
> INSERT INTO OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION(FVPO_VPA_ID,DSAI_ID,FVPO_price_product_id,FVPO_material_number,FVPO_Quantity) VALUES ('17270',40106,'PR000349059','SP000748370',5565604);
> INSERT INTO OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION(FVPO_VPA_ID,DSAI_ID,FVPO_price_product_id,FVPO_material_number,FVPO_Quantity) VALUES ('17270',40109,'PR000349059','SP000748364',1962898);
> INSERT INTO OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION(FVPO_VPA_ID,DSAI_ID,FVPO_price_product_id,FVPO_material_number,FVPO_Quantity) VALUES ('17270',40108,'PR000349059','SP000748366',2589732);
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select FVPO_VPA_ID , FVPO_price_product_id , FVPO_material_number 
>      , sum(FVPO_Quantity) as FVPO_Quantity                       
> from   OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION
> where  FVPO_price_product_id = 'PR000349059'
> and    FVPO_VPA_ID = '17270'                        
> group by FVPO_VPA_ID, FVPO_price_product_id, FVPO_material_number  
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> FVPO_VPA_ID | FVPO_price_product_id | FVPO_material_number | FVPO_Quantity
> :---------- | :-------------------- | :------------------- | ------------:
> 17270       | PR000349059           | SP000748364          |       1962898
> 17270       | PR000349059           | SP000748366          |       2589732
> 17270       | PR000349059           | SP000748370          |       5565604
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(
>    DSAI_ID                   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR       VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
>   ,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR         VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
>   ,dsai_subito_transfer_flag VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40106,'PR000349059','SP000748370','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40109,'PR000349059','SP000748364','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40108,'PR000349059','SP000748366','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (11670,'PR000349059','SP000010709','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40096,'PR000349059','SP000748362','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40099,'PR000349059','SP000748132','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40100,'PR000349059','SP000748130','Y');
> INSERT INTO OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM(DSAI_ID,DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR,DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR,dsai_subito_transfer_flag) VALUES (40101,'PR000349059','SP000748128','Y');
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select DSAI_ID, DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR, DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR          
> from   OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM
> where  DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR = 'PR000349059'
> and    dsai_subito_transfer_flag = 'Y'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DSAI_ID | DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR | DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR
> ------: | :------------------ | :----------------
>   11670 | PR000349059         | SP000010709      
>   40096 | PR000349059         | SP000748362      
>   40099 | PR000349059         | SP000748132      
>   40100 | PR000349059         | SP000748130      
>   40101 | PR000349059         | SP000748128      
>   40106 | PR000349059         | SP000748370      
>   40108 | PR000349059         | SP000748366      
>   40109 | PR000349059         | SP000748364
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     fct.FVPO_VPA_ID 
>   , dim.DSAI_ID
>   , fct.FVPO_price_product_id 
>   , fct.FVPO_material_number 
>   , dim.DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR
>   , dim.DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR
>   , fct.FVPO_Quantity  
> FROM OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM dim
> LEFT JOIN OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION fct ON dim.DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR = fct.FVPO_material_number
> WHERE dim.DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR = 'PR000349059'
> AND dim.dsai_subito_transfer_flag = 'Y'
> ORDER BY
>     fct.FVPO_VPA_ID 
>   , dim.DSAI_ID
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> FVPO_VPA_ID | DSAI_ID | FVPO_price_product_id | FVPO_material_number | DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR | DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR | FVPO_Quantity
> :---------- | ------: | :-------------------- | :------------------- | :------------------ | :---------------- | ------------:
> null        |   11670 | null                  | null                 | PR000349059         | SP000010709       |          null
> null        |   40096 | null                  | null                 | PR000349059         | SP000748362       |          null
> null        |   40099 | null                  | null                 | PR000349059         | SP000748132       |          null
> null        |   40100 | null                  | null                 | PR000349059         | SP000748130       |          null
> null        |   40101 | null                  | null                 | PR000349059         | SP000748128       |          null
> 17270       |   40106 | PR000349059           | SP000748370          | PR000349059         | SP000748370       |       5565604
> 17270       |   40108 | PR000349059           | SP000748366          | PR000349059         | SP000748366       |       2589732
> 17270       |   40109 | PR000349059           | SP000748364          | PR000349059         | SP000748364       |       1962898
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4cd252008265d3648e7a4409584afaa)*

This is as far as I care to take this. I did not include the group by part of 1 query which you will need to put back in, but hopefully you can now see the purpose of providing "sample data" (not images, but DDL and as inserts) and the "expected result" (also not an image). With data and code we can actually run things. By the way I didn't type in all that data, I was able to reverse engineer the comment - but even that wasn't something you should rely on us to do for you in future.

**ADDED:** to introduce the wanted `group by` subquery, I suggest the following:

```
SELECT
    fct.FVPO_VPA_ID 
  , dim.DSAI_ID
  , fct.FVPO_price_product_id 
  , fct.FVPO_material_number 
  , dim.DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR
  , dim.DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR
  , fct.FVPO_Quantity  
FROM OP_DIM_SALES_ITEM dim
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT FVPO_VPA_ID, FVPO_price_product_id ,FVPO_material_number, SUM(FVPO_Quantity) AS FVPO_Quantity
        FROM OP_FCT_SDDB_VPA_POSITION
        GROUP BY FVPO_VPA_ID, FVPO_price_product_id ,FVPO_material_number
        ) fct ON dim.DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR = fct.FVPO_material_number
WHERE dim.DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR = 'PR000349059'
AND dim.dsai_subito_transfer_flag = 'Y'
ORDER BY
    fct.FVPO_VPA_ID 
  , dim.DSAI_ID
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to to get the missing materials in the main fact table. Please see :           VPA_ID DSAI_ID PRODUCT_ID MATERIAL_ QUANTITY
17270 40106 PR000349059 SP000748370 5565604
17270 40109 PR000349059 SP000748364 1962898
17270 40108 PR000349059 SP000748366 2589732
         11670 PR000349059 SP000010709 
          40096 PR000349059 SP000748362 
          40099 PR000349059 SP000748132 
           40100 PR000349059 SP000748130 
          40101 PR000349059 SP000748128

Comment: additionally it shd be dim.DSAI_PRPR_SAP_MATNR = fct.FVPO_price_product_id.

Comment: turned out to be `ON dim.DSAI_SP_SAP_MATNR = fct.FVPO_material_number` once I had some tables to work with

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful effort but unfortunately I still miss the materials and null values. I think somehow the where clause is not working because I expect all three rows from fact table and additionally 5 rows from dimension table with DSAI ID, material, while qty and vpa id NULL , I used group by also and searched on ID 17270 and NULL but I get only 3 records:  I will add picture of results. Where FVPO_VPA_ID in ('17270',NULL)

Comment: I won't be contributing more on this. I have demonstrated how to achieve the desired output - that's the end of this question as far as I am concerned. Feel free to ask a new question. `NB:` Your natural inclination appears to be to use pictures - but you should use text just as I did. `PLEASE` read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: by the way - to introduce the `GROUP BY` I suggest you do it as a subquery, I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello experts this is an example of the output , yellow part is the current output and rest is the one i want to add it from the material dimension which have missing materials. There is no quantity and vpa id for these materials:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr0ak.png)

Comment: Don't use images of data or code, copy and paste text, this has many advantages. Please take some time to read about how to ask great questions . Use the help below. e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question Also, don't add answers to expand on your question - this isn't a forum. Just edit your question instead. Leave answers for those trying to help you.